# how to shift x axis labesl on line plot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I'm using pandas to work with a data set and am tring to use a simple line plot with error bars to show the end results. It's all working great except that the plot looks funny.

By default, it will put my 2 data groups at the far left and right of the plot, which obscures the error bar to the point that it's not useful (the error bars in this case are key to intpretation so I want them plainly visible).

Now, I fix that problem by setting xlim to open up some space on either end of the x axis so that the error bars are plainly visible, but then I have an offset from where the x labels are to where the actual x data is.

Here is a simplified example that shows the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df6 = pd.DataFrame( [-0.07,0.08] , index = ['A','B'])
df6.plot(kind='line', linewidth=2, yerr = [ [0.1,0.1],[0.1,0.1 ] ], elinewidth=2,ecolor='green') 

plt.xlim(-0.2,1.2)  # Make some room at ends to see error bars 

plt.show()
```

I tried to include a plot (image) showing the problem but I cannot post images yet, having just joined up and do not have anough points yet to post images.

What I want to know is: How do I shift these labels over one tick to the right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean the label is blocking the data?

Comment: No this is just a problem of aligning the data labels to the data itself (so that the data for group A is at the same x position as the label A).

Comment: Meanwhile I think I have found a good way to solve this, but again since I'm new it won't let me answer my own question until some number of hours has passed. I'll post it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out I found a solution, which I will jsut post here in case anyone else has this same issue in the future.

Basically, it all seems to work better in the case of a line plot if you just specify both the labels and the ticks in the same place at the same time. At least that was helpful for me. It sort of forces you to keep the length of those two lists the same, which seems to make the assignment between ticks and labels more well behaved (simple 1:1 in this case).

So I coudl fix my problem by including something like this:

```
plt.xticks([0, 1], ['A','B'] )
```

right after the xlim statement in code from original question. Now the A and B align perfectly with the place where the data is plotted, not offset from it.

Using above solution it works, but is less good-looking since now the x grid is very coarse (this is purely and aesthetic consideration). I could fix that by using a different xtick statement like:

```
plt.xticks([-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], ['','A','','','','','B',''])
```

This gives me nice looking grid and the data where I need it, but of course is very contrived-looking here. In the actual program I'd find a way to make that less clunky.

Hope that is of some help to fellow seekers....